# Return value with if and vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I'm trying to create a formula that can help me maintain a list.

I have drawing numbers and revisions on one sheet. I need to like bring that to the main sheet for each drawing number that is on the main sheet.

Like if the second sheet is like

```
Rev    Drawing number    
,      xx_B_200_50
1      xx_B_200_51
```

I want the formula to return it like this on the main page

```
Rev    Drawing number
00     xx_B_200_50
01     xx_B_200_51
```

I have been trying these, but dont know how to get to the goal!!

```
=VLOOKUP(G19;'secondsheet'!$I:$K;3;FALSE);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to use the *Drawing number* to look up a corresponding value on another sheet.

In your data sample, one row has a comma and the other row has the number 1. You seem to want to return this as `00` and `01`

I don't quite understand the logic how a comma translates to `00`. You may want to explain that a bit more.

In order to return the "Rev" column by looking up the Drawing Number you cannot use Vlookup in this case, because Vlookup can only return a value to the right of the column where the value was found.

Assuming that "Rev" is in column A and "Drawing number" is in column B in both sheets, you can use an Index/Match combination to return the cell value.

```
=Index(Sheet2!$A:$A,Match(Sheet1!B1,Sheet2!$b:$b,0))
```

That formula will return the value from the cell in column A of sheet 2 where column B of sheet 2 has the same value as B1 on sheet 1.

You can wrap this formula in formulas for error checking or formattin a number with a leading zero. You can also wrap it in a formula to return a `00` if the result is a comma.

Also, since you seem to be using European settings, you need to replace all commas in the formula above with semicolons. Like this:

```
=Index(Sheet2!$A:$A;Match(Sheet1!B1;Sheet2!$b:$b;0))
```

If that does not help, post more information, a sample file, a screenshot. Help us help you.

Edit after you posted the sample file.

You are trying to use a formula with several conditions but you are not applying the OR correctly.

The OR() function cannot be used to connect two IF statements. IF() has the syntax `IF(condition, do when true, do when false)`. So what you want to cover with "Or" needs to go into the `do when false` bit. You may want to change the formula to this:

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH($B:$B,Sheet2!$B:$B,0))=".","00",IF(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH($B:$B,Sheet2!$B:$B,0))="1","01","other"))
```

You can replace the `other` bit in the formula with yet another nested IF to include another "or" condition.

Comment: Thanks you. I have just made a excel file and used your code.  Here is the link. I couldn't add it to my previous post. As you can see i get error when i want to convert "1" to "01" and "." to "00". I need as least from 00 to 05.  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=48979453526771388742

Comment: I added more details to my answer